# MATLAB's graph performance

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, matlab, graph

Im developing WindowsForm using C# and VisualStudio. The program launch a .exe done in Matlab and after this .exe finish, it generates a huge amount of data in several .mat files and i have to plot this data in a chart (not all at the same time). The user select 1 of this "signals" an it has to be drawn.

Depending on the configuration, each signal can have from ~10.000 values to ~500.000, and when i plot signals with this amount of data the chart control dont respond smoothly, also zooming in/out takes ages. When drawing more signals at the same time, the control becomes even more unstable.

In the other hand, if i plot the signals from Matlab itself, the job is done almost inmediatly. The zoom works perfectly and you can draw as many signals as u want because the performance is maintained.

Why there is such a big performance difference between Matlab and C#?

What can i do to improve C# performance?

EDIT: Im using the standard chart control provided with VisualStudio.

Comment: Depending on what version and edition of Visual Studio, there's more than one chart control "included".  Is it `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010, and yes, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what chart control you're using, but it's surely something not designed for large data sets.  Use something based on OpenGL for your plot.

In my experience, I'm actually quite annoyed at the *poor* performance of Matlab pan-and-zoom with in excess of 30 million data points, while a C#+OpenGL implementation has a frame rate 10 times higher.

(Among other reasons, it seems that MatLab entirely fails to cull portions of the dataset that are far off-screen -- if you have a monotonically increasing time axis, for instance, this is a very easy optimization that reaps huge benefits)

Comment: I edited my question to include the info you requested. Anyway, im also telm ling you through this comment, iusing the standard chart control provided with VS. I also tried OxyPlot (wich performs better than microsoft's control, but is a pain to work with). ¿Any OpenGL recomendations for chart controls? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've got more data than there are pixels to represent it.  It sounds like your chart control is taking the brute force approach: draw every data point, even if there are 1000 data points per column of pixels on the control.

Whether you've got access to the chart control's source code or not the solution is going to be the same: you must reduce the number of drawing calls.  You need to filter the data down to a more manageable size.  In the case of a line chart, if your control is 500 pixels wide then it shouldn't be trying to draw more than 500 lines.

If you've got access to the chart control's code then you can have it reduce the data set internally.  Otherwise you'll need to manage an abstract view of the data set externally, and pass the view instead of the full data set into your chart control.  The view will need to be updated as the user changes zoom levels, etc...  Unfortunately depending on whether the underlying chart control knows to automatically clip the data set to what's visible, panning might be a bit of a pain to implement.  You'd need to perform clipping yourself whenever the user pans the view but also include data points at the extreme ends of each axis so that scrollbars remain consistent.

Make things easier on yourself by first ensuring the original data set is sorted on the X axis value.  Sorting only needs to be done once, and then you can build a view at any zoom level relatively quickly.  A O(log N) search can identify indices at the start and end of the visible range, and from there it's trivial to extract X samples for your view.  If the original data is known to be taken at fixed intervals over the X axis then you don't even need the O(log N) search; you can calculate the indices of the visual range directly.

Comment: At the beginning i thought this was much more complicated than looking for a good graph library, but i've been thinking in this approachh and right now seems a pretty viable option. I think i'll give it a try